# unexpected performance boost with OpenMP critical section

Tags: c++, c, performance, openmp

Why do I have a benefit in terms of execution time with the following code?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  #pragma omp  critical
  {
    funcall1();
    funcall2();

    for(j=0;j<size2;j++)
    {
      funcall3();
     }

  }

}
```

it runs twice the serial version but I dunno why

Comment: Possibly cache coherence if it is reserving a single core for those steps

Comment: the code seems to be executed by 4 cores.. 

Can a thread enter the critical section if the previous thread execute a function call?

Could you explain your answer better please?

Comment: Each of the outer loop runs on a sep core, the inner loop will be locked into the core by the critical and so any cached values in the function calls will be avialable for the next call

Comment: even with num_threads(1) the performance gain is the same.. I am very confused..

Comment: Given to the comments about I would think about an internal compiler optimization. This would also explain the speed up with num_threads(1).

The compiler knows about the independency of the different for blocks. I do not know what the function blocks do, but you may have a chance that the compiler optimizes cache usage or something like that. With the pragmas you give quite good information to the compiler.

Comment: Try comparing assembler output

Comment: What are we comparing to what exactly? Are we comparing with both pragma's to with neither? Or are we comparing with and without the 'critical' but with the 'parallel' in both?

Comment: Can you post the "serial" version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the second variable j can scope optimized, it could potentially be unrolled.